# Node-knex (postgres) Connection terminated unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, server, postman, knex.js

i'm trying to connect my server with my database, i'm  trying to register a user in postman to see if it updates the username in postgres, but i'm getting the below error message on my server once sending the POST in postman
const error = this._ending ? new Error('Connection terminated') : new Error('Connection terminated unexpectedly')
^

Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
at Connection. (C:\Users\mekstein\Documents\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:132:73)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
at Connection.emit (node:events:527:28)
at Socket. (C:\Users\mekstein\Documents\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:107:12)
at Socket.emit (node:events:539:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:

this is my code for server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex')


const db = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'postgres',
    port: 3001,
    password : 'Moshe6700',
    database : 'smart-brain'
  }
});



const app = express();


const database = {
    users: [
    {
        id: '123',
        name: 'john',
        password: 'cookies',
        email: 'john@gmail.com',
        entries: 0,
        joined: new Date()
    },
    {
        id: '124',
        name: 'Sally',
        password: 'bananas',
        email: 'sally@gmail.com',
        entries: 0,
        joined: new Date()
    }
    ],
    login: [
      {
        id: '987',
        hash: '',
        email: 'john@gmail.com'
      }
    ]
}

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(database.users);
})

app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
//  bcrypt.compare("pears", '$2a$10$HNdjMT7A6hNEgDy.khan2OU9QEGXX8lxH7Kp4bmrUTzJio1lFzh7y', function(err, res) {
//      console.log('first guess', res)
// });
// bcrypt.compare("veggies", '$2a$10$HNdjMT7A6hNEgDy.khan2OU9QEGXX8lxH7Kp4bmrUTzJio1lFzh7y', function(err, res) {
//     console.log('second guess', res)
// });

    if(req.body.email === database.users[0].email && 
        req.body.password === database.users[0].password) {
        res.json(database.users[0]);
}else {
    res.status(400).json('error logging in')
}
})

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { email, name, password} = req.body;
    db('users').insert({
        email: email,
        name: name,
        joined: new Date()
    }).then(console.log)
    res.json(database.users[database.users.length-1])
})
app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(users => {
        if(users.id === id) {
            found = true;
            return res.json(users)

        }
    })
    if (!found) {
        res.status(400).json('not found')
    }
})

app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(user => {
        if(user.id === id) {
            found = true;
            user.entries++
            return res.json(user.entries)

        }
    })
    if (!found) {
        res.status(400).json('not found')
    }
})




app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('app is running on port 3001')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Go to pgAdmin, right-click on Servers, register server, and connection, and see the port **NUMBER**. Then put that NUMBER in the code. connection:

```
{
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'postgres',
    **port: NUMBER,**
    password: 'Moshe6700',
    database: 'smart-brain'
  }
```